# How to clear /clean-up pg_xlog directory?

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have found myself in a situation where the pg_xlog folder contains 80GB of data maybe because wrong configuration

how to purge or cleanup the files under pg_xlog?

```
/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_xlog
[root@hadoop02 pg_xlog]# ls -ltr | more
total 53887180
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 19  2017 0000000100000000000000F1
-rw-------. 1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 19  2017 0000000100000000000000F2
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 19  2017 0000000100000000000000F3
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 19  2017 0000000100000000000000F4
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 19  2017 0000000100000000000000F5
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2017 0000000100000000000000F6
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2017 0000000100000000000000F7
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2017 0000000100000000000000F8
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2017 0000000100000000000000F9
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2017 0000000100000000000000FA
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2017 0000000100000000000000FB
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2017 0000000100000000000000FC
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 20  2017 0000000100000000000000FD
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2017 0000000100000000000000FE
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2017 000000010000000100000000
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2017 000000010000000100000001
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2017 000000010000000100000002
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2017 000000010000000100000003
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2017 000000010000000100000004
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 21  2017 000000010000000100000005
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2017 000000010000000100000006
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2017 000000010000000100000007
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2017 000000010000000100000008
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2017 000000010000000100000009
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2017 00000001000000010000000A
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 22  2017 00000001000000010000000B
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 23  2017 00000001000000010000000C
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 23  2017 00000001000000010000000D
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 23  2017 00000001000000010000000E
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 23  2017 00000001000000010000000F
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 23  2017 000000010000000100000010
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 23  2017 000000010000000100000011
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 23  2017 000000010000000100000012
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 24  2017 000000010000000100000013
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 24  2017 000000010000000100000014
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 24  2017 000000010000000100000015
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 24  2017 000000010000000100000016
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 24  2017 000000010000000100000017
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 24  2017 000000010000000100000018
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 24  2017 000000010000000100000019
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 24  2017 00000001000000010000001A
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 24  2017 00000001000000010000001B
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 25  2017 00000001000000010000001C
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 25  2017 00000001000000010000001D
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 25  2017 00000001000000010000001E
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 25  2017 00000001000000010000001F
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 25  2017 000000010000000100000020
-rw-------  1 postgres postgres 16777216 Sep 25  2017 000000010000000100000021
```

Comment: If you want remove all files `rm /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_xlog/*` or `find /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_xlog -type f -exec rm {} \;`

Comment: what ? you are really ? this are wall files!

Comment: What are *wall files*?

Comment: Duplicate of https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/166143/how-to-clear-pg-xlog-directory

Comment: stop/start postgresql not help to clear the files on my server